Pycharm start project is not creating venv
When I start a project with Pycharm and try to start a project, my virtual environment directory is not being created. Here is what it looks like on my computer:

Now I can manually create a venv by using
python -m venv venv then use .\env\scripts\activate but doing so is messing up my template folder location and static location. When I start a project I also used to create an app. I kept my static and templates folder inside the app. But when I go  to settings.py in the project I can not find my static and templates folder in suggestion. Even if I manually include them, when running the project I see this warning prompt:

But when I run the project the js files and all the static files are included properly. I thought it could be due to the previous browser cache. So I cleaned the whole browser and ran the project, but it runs absolutely fine. My problem there is that my static files don't show up in suggestions then. I am not new to Django and have worked on 3/4 project for my university and one internship. But I haven't faced this issue before.  But I absolutely could not find any solution to these problems.
Here are my two questions:

Is there any way I can resolve this virtual environment problem?
Is there any way to resolve the issue in the second picture?


(1) Have you tried to create the virtualenv manually after creating the project? Does it work then? (See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html.) (2) Did you turn on PyCharm's Django support? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support7.html

Yes, I manually created the venv using the command lines I stated. I could not create a venv in pycharm without using the command lines. But using the command lines came with it's own sets of problems, which I included in the second shared picture.

you created a venv named venv but you're trying to activate a venv named env

Can you show your static/templates configuration in your settings.py?

My problem there is that my static files don't show up in suggestions then... Since your project runs fine despite this warning, then I'm thinking it's probably not an issue with Django but with PyCharm

Have you tried executing the venv command with an absolute path??
like python -m venv C:/django https://django.seolpyo.com/entry/17/

There were multiple options but yet you chose Pure Python. PyCharm is an IDE.

This has already been mentioned, but I wanted to clarify further:
When you create a virtual environment using python -m venv {venv-folder-name}, you are specifying the name of the folder where the virtual environment will be set up. Inside this folder, you'll find an activate script.
For example, if you name your virtual environment thisvenv, you should run:
python -m venv thisvenv

After running this command, you'll find the activate script within the thisvenv folder. On POSIX systems (like Linux and macOS), it will be located in the bin directory. On Windows, it will be in the Scripts directory. To activate the virtual environment, use:
On POSIX systems:
source thisvenv/bin/activate

On Windows:
.\thisvenv\Scripts\activate

This will adjust your PATH to use the Python executable from the virtual environment.
